# Not able to add android platform to cordova in mac osx

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Creating android project...
/Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                    ^

Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at /Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:158:19
    at _fulfilled (/Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:469:11)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
Error: /Users/vishwanth/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:818:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you havn't add the android tools to your path. Try to execute

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/path-to-your-android-sdk-folder/platform-tools:/path-to-your-android-sdk-folder/tools
cordova platform add android
```

If it works you can add the android tools to your path permanetly by adding the export line to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile. Further details in the [Android platform guide under "Install the Android SDK"](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for this step is incomplete, to say the least. In August, 2016 you have to...

1. Go to Android developer's site. Don't download Android Studio. Scroll to the bottom of the page and download the "command line tools" for Mac.
2. Unzip this file and add it to your /Users/your_name/Library folder.
3. In the folder, open a terminal and type "android" to open the SDK manager
4. install platform tools from this manager
5. open .bash_profile
6. add, "export PATH=/Users/your_name/Library/android-sdk-macosx/tools:$PATH"
7. add, "export PATH=/Users/your_name/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:$PATH" and leave .bash_profile open
8. now you have to install Apache ant, get the .tar.gz [from here](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi)
9. add the unzipped folder to /Users/your_name/Library folder
10. in .bash_profile add "export ANT_HOME=/Users/your_name/Library/apache-ant-1.9.7"
11. and also in .bash_profile, add "PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin:
12. close and re-open the Terminal in the Cordova project folder (reloads updated .bash_profile")
13. type "android" to open the Android SDK manager
14. check the box next to **Android 4.4.2 (API 19)**

...Now, in Terminal, you should be able to

```
cordova platform add android
```

...and it should work.

Thank you to about 15 other StackOverflow answers for the pieces to this puzzle. Good luck!